# Telegram bot how to handle geolocation via php

Tags: php, geolocation, telegram, telegram-bot

## help!

I am writing telegram bot, I request the geo-position via the button with `request_location`, in response the point on the map comes. I can not figure out how to pass this point to `$ lon; $ lat` sorry for my bad english.thanks

```
$output = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'),true);
$id = $output['message']['chat']['id'];
$token='***';
$ApiKey='***';      
$message= $output['message']['text'];
$Location=$output['longitude']['latitude'];
switch ($message) {
case '/start':
    $message = 'Привет! Нажми отправить местоположение чтобы начать.';
    sendMessage($token, $id, $message . KeyboardMenu());
    break;
case $Location:
    $lat = $Location['latitude'];
    $lon = $Location['longitude'];
    if (isset($Location['longitude']['latitude']))
        {
            $message = "Отлично! ваше местонахождение определено." .$lat. $lon;
        }
   else
       {
            $message ="error";
       }
   sendMessage($token, $id, $message,$lat,$lon . KeyboardMenu().get_address($lat, $lon, $ApiKey));
break;
 default:
    $message='Неправильный запрос.';
    sendMessage($token,$id,$message.KeyboardMenu());
function sendMessage($token, $id,$message)
{
file_get_contents("https://api.telegram.org/bot" . $token . "/sendMessage?
chat_id=" . $id . "&text=".$message);
}

function KeyboardMenu(){
    $buttons = [[['text'=>"Отправить местоположение", 
'request_location'=>true]],[['text'=>"Показать автосервисы"]],[['text'=>"Справка"]]];
     $keyboard =json_encode($keyboard=['keyboard' => $buttons,
                                        'resize_keyboard' => true,
                                        'one_time_keyboard'=> false,
                                        'selective' => true]);
   $reply_markup ='&reply_markup='.$keyboard.'';
   return $reply_markup;
}
```

---

thanks!

Comment: Please write your problem in English

Comment: The only thing I can understand on this post is `help!`

Comment: What you tried show the code!!!

Comment: Please edit the question.